# Running web services in XAMPP

Tags: web-services, xampp

I'm working in a web application which retrieves some data via a php web service.I'm testing it in localhost
But always the web service returns data.null

the application works fine in my peer's machine

I'm using XAMPP version is 2.5.8 which is running on windows XP

I need to know whether do I have do any configuration in XAMPP in order to run php web services...????

any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with your setup, it could be the database, missing module or anything really. Did you check the logs in `\xampp\apache\logs\` and can you see any error?

**Edit:**

Try to make PHP displays all the errors. Search for `error_reporting` or `display_errors` in your code and set it to this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

If you can't find these lines, just add them at the top of your index.php (or whatever name you are using). Then run the web service and it might give you some error messages.

Comment: Hi Laurent,well I just checked the log.there is no log entry about the web service.

Comment: By the way, what does return "null". Are you testing directly in the browser or through some web application (Flash, etc.)?